# Cannot map "display" and "value" fields in a combobox component using Ext JS 4. Shows [object Object]

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, store, extjs4.2

I wonder somebody could help me in order to map information of an object array into a combobox using ExtJS 4.2.

The object I have is described in the following image:

[image]

I want to use this "products" array as a Store for a combobox component.

I defined the component as follow:

```
var selector = {
                xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                anchor: '50%',
                layout: {type: 'hbox', pack: 'start'},        
                items: [{
                     xtype: 'combobox',                
                     allowBlank: false,
                     editable: false,
                     fieldLabel: 'Products (' + products.length + ')',
                     itemId: 'productsInvolved',
                     store: products,
                     displayField: 'key.productType',
                     valueField: 'key.productId'     
             }]
             };
             return selector;
```

But I can't figure out why it is returning: [Object object] when I show it in the user interface, it must shows "GENERAL" and has the value of "123456".

I have tried converting it to a ArrayStore, but no succeed. Some idea or clue on this, please?

I really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

What I would try would be to add two computed fields to your Model like this:

```
Ext.define('Product', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'keyProductType',
            convert: function(value, record) {
                return record.data.key.productType;
                //or
                //return record.get('Key').productType;
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'keyProductId',
            convert: function(value, record) {
                return record.data.key.productId;
                //or
                //return record.get('Key').productId;
            }
        },
        ..
        ..
    ]
});
```

And then use these new field names on your combo

```
displayField: 'keyProductType',
valueField: 'keyProductId'
```

Note: I havent testeed this yet

Answer (score -1):

I suggest only one change in above code.

```
Ext.define('Product', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'keyProductType',
            convert: function(value, record) {
                return record.data.key.data.productType;
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'keyProductId',
            convert: function(value, record) {
                return record.data.key.data.productId;
            }
        },
        ..
        ..
    ]
});
```

And then use these new field names on your combo

```
displayField: 'keyProductType',
valueField: 'keyProductId'
```